# Is there a spelling library that recognizes incomplete words?

Tags: c++, spell-checking, spelling

My use case is the following: given a string, recognize all valid words starting at the beginning of the string. For example:

```
blueberryqqq
```

should output:

```
blue
blueberry
```

To do that, I have a dictionary structure that uses a [`trie<char>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). For example, if my dictionary consists only of the two words above, it would like this:

```
b->l->u->e->\0
          ->b->e->r->r->y->\0
```

When I investigate my input string, the spell-checking process can tell me, as I go from letter to letter whether:

1. I'm on the path to a valid word
2. I have found a valid word
3. I am not on the path to a valid word

Note that these are flags and both `1` and `2` can be true at the same time. With that approach, I can efficiently find both `blue` and `blueberry` in one go and stop trying immediately when I reach the `y`. Continuing with the example, here's what happens as I go from letter to letter:

```
b:1, l:1, u:1, e:1|2, b:1, e:1, r:1, r:1, y:2
```

When I see `1|2`, I know that "blue" is valid word but I also know to keep going further down the string because my dictionary tells me there are more words possible. Once I reach the `y`, I stop. Quite efficient as I visit each letter only once for all valid words and I stop spell-checking as soon as the dictionary tells me there is no point in going further. Perfect!

**My problem** is that my dictionary trie is built from /usr/share/dict/words  and that file does not contain the plural form of "bluberry" which is "blueberries" and in general won't contain all the "derivatives" of all the words. So if the input string is `blueberriesqqq`, I will only get `blue` as valid.

If I were to use a spell-checking library like `aspell` or `hunspell`, *as far I as I can tell*, I would need to spellcheck all sub-strings individually! e.g. `b`, `bl`, `blu`, etc. Quite inefficient! Not only that, but I wouldn't know when to stop checking. e.g. How do I know there aren't any words that start with `blueberriesqq`?

So, my question becomes: is there a spell-checking library out there that would accommodate my use case?

Note that spelling suggestions wouldn't cut it. Passing `blueb` to aspell does not return any spelling suggestions which start with `blueb`. Thus, I would end my search even though there is still the possibility of more valid words down the line.

Comment: You may expand your dictionary into list of words with something like `aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > my.dict` to build your trie.

Comment: This is usually best done with a sorted wordlist, not a dictionary. By taking advantage of sorting, you can find the spot in the sorted list that begins with blu... and each new letter has `log(N)` lookup and without any memory bloat trying to expand this stuff out with substrings, etc. The further you get into the word, the faster it gets, but it's never too slow.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure you've implemented the trie correctly? Looks to me you can build the tree in *O(n)* (with *n* the size of the dictionary (counting characters), and *O(n)* to lookup a string. But with O(1) update time when a new characters is given: you simply need to keep track of the *active node*.

Comment: @screwnut: you can turn your question from looking for dictionary tool, into something to retrieve all word with derivatives from `/usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: Furthermore there are a lot of algorithms in natural language processing that can turn a word into it's plular quite effectively.

Comment: @Jarod42, I've followed your first suggestion and was able to move forward. Thanks.

Comment: @VoidStar I will explore that option.

Comment: @Captain Oblivious I'm not looking for a recommendation based on feelings or personal preference. I have a clear cut use case with a clear cut yes/no/alternate-approach answer.

Comment: @CommuSoft What you describe is exactly what I do.

Comment: @screwnut Irrelevant. Requests to recommend a library are off-topic regardless if you're asking for personal opinions or not.